# Change videos frame rate (fps) in python

Tags: python, video, frame, frame-rate

I would like to know if it is possible to change the fps of a video.
I have videos of 24, 25 and 30 fps and I would like to change them all to 30 fps.

Thank you

Comment: Not without powerful external tools. So your best bet is to use one of those ffmpeg-wrappers.

Comment: I have opencv and ffmpeg but I don't know how to do it. I am trying ffmpeg -r "30" -i "input.avi" -vcodec "copy" "output.avi" but it doesn't work

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding has an answer about how to change the framerate without re-encoding, but it's quite a long process. Doesn't need Python, though, just ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem:

```py
import subprocess

c = 'ffmpeg -y -i ' + video_input_path + ' -r 30 -s 112x112 -c:v libx264 -b:v 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart '+video_output_path

subprocess.call(c, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

With `moviepy` one can simply try this:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip(video_input_path)
clip.write_videofile(video_output_path, fps=30)
#clip.reader.close()
```